# Iptables and conditional statements. Is it possible?

Tags: iptables

I tried a search but i was unsuccessful, in the case i'm sorry and i will appreciate the redirect.

I had this problem in mind: a computer with mac address **M** is sending packets through an openwrt router (or a linux based system) and i would like, just to try the possibility, to let go through a packet from **M** but the packet immediately after has to be dropped, then accepted again, then dropped and so on.

So if the computer with mac **M** sends 20 packets, only 10 will pass, the other 10 will be dropped. In a verbose way the wanted result is: accept, drop, accept, drop, accept, drop, accept, drop, etc...

A pseudocode explanation

```
condition=ACCEPT
for each packet {
  if ( packet_is_sent_from_adapter_with_mac_M ) {
    if (condition == ACCEPT) {
      accept_packet
      condition=DROP
    }
    else {
      drop_packet
      condition=ACCEPT
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible? After googling a bit seems that iptables doesn't support any conditional statements or scripting.

And if it is possible, what about a general condition "drop X consecutive packets after Y consecutive accepts" ?

**addition1**: The question in general is *"flow control" is not allowed in iptables?* or better, since conditional decisions are based on a state (*condition* in the pseudocode), how can we save the state related of a certain condition in iptables and do something checking this state?

**addition2**: In the comments additional tools (tc) are suggested to achieve flow control (i mean if statements, loops, etc.), feel free to suggest combination (maybe with a bit of explanation). Thanks!

Comment: As Janne says, `iptables` is a good UNIX tool so can probably be tortured into doing flow control.  But `tc` is the traffic-shaping tool and is probably a lot better for this!  The two tools *combined* (eg, `iptables` to tag packets based on iptables-type criteria, then `tc` to shape based on tagging) can be even more powerful.

Comment: Ah yep i did Qos control with tc and filtering. So combining them i can achieve flow control?

Comment: It depends what you want to achieve.  Even the description you've given above is imprecise: of those 20 packets, every other packet is to be dropped.  But what happens to the 21st?  If you want precise guidance, you will need to precisely state your question.

Comment: Of course, but, since i know the question, i need feedback for the others to check how clear i was (plus i'm not a native english speaker) and to improve the question. Let me edit it again.

Comment: @MadHatter question edited, i hope now it is more clear.

Answer (score 4):

For your needs, iptables `statistic` extension might work. Set the mode to `nth`, `every` to `2` and attach that to your `DROP` rule. So maybe something like

```
iptables -A INPUT -m statistic --mode nth --every 2 -m mac --mac-source xx:xx:xx:xx:xx -j DROP
```

should work.

iptables-extensions man page says about statistic module this:

```
statistic
This module matches packets based on some statistic condition. It supports two distinct modes settable with the --mode option.

Supported options:

--mode mode
    Set the matching mode of the matching rule, supported modes are random and nth. 
[!] --probability p
    Set the probability for a packet to be randomly matched. It only works with the random mode. p must be within 0.0 and 1.0. The supported granularity is in 1/2147483648th increments. 
[!] --every n
    Match one packet every nth packet. It works only with the nth mode (see also the --packet option). 
--packet p
    Set the initial counter value (0 <= p <= n-1, default 0) for the nth mode.
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! (cannot upvote sorry) But in general "flow control" is not allowed in iptables?

Comment: I'm afraid not, though with some creative jumping from chain to chain and the use of extensions you can usually work things out. But not in a straightforward way you want. Or, if I'm wrong, I'm very happy if someone shows me the way to enlightenment! :)

Comment: Well me too. I just saw this cn.cs.unibas.ch/pub/doc/2010-msthGraf.pdf yesterday.

Comment: another nice idea (a bit verbose but ok) http://sgros.blogspot.de/2011/09/implementing-turing-machine-using.html